# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, spring-mvc

I'm trying to set up an application for Google app engine, and I cannot make it work. I'm have everything set up with maven but spring its not working.

I've been trough a lot of configuration setting and I cannot get it done!!

Here you have the stack trace:

```
05-oct-2010 0:56:54 com.google.appengine.tools.info.RemoteVersionFactory getVersion
INFO: Unable to access https://appengine.google.com/api/updatecheck?runtime=java&release=1.3.7&timestamp=1282754401&api_versions=['1.0']
java.net.UnknownHostException: appengine.google.com
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:177)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:550)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:141)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:163)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:394)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:529)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:272)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:329)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:172)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:801)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:158)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1049)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:234)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1010)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.info.RemoteVersionFactory.getVersion(RemoteVersionFactory.java:76)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.info.UpdateCheck.checkForUpdates(UpdateCheck.java:99)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.info.UpdateCheck.doNagScreen(UpdateCheck.java:174)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.info.UpdateCheck.maybePrintNagScreen(UpdateCheck.java:142)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:150)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.<init>(DevAppServerMain.java:113)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:89)
05-oct-2010 0:56:55 com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
05-oct-2010 0:56:55 com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
INFO: Successfully processed E:\development\Tune My Party\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
05-oct-2010 0:56:55 com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed E:\development\Tune My Party\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF/web.xml
05-oct-2010 3:56:55 com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: jetty-6.1.x
05-oct-2010 3:56:57 com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
ADVERTENCIA: EXCEPTION 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:151)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:91)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:71)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:73)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:242)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:185)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:147)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:219)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:164)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.<init>(DevAppServerMain.java:113)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:89)
05-oct-2010 3:56:57 com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl log
GRAVE: [1286251017245000] javax.servlet.ServletContext log: unavailable
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:79)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:242)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:185)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:147)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:219)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:164)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.<init>(DevAppServerMain.java:113)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:89)

05-oct-2010 3:56:57 com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
ADVERTENCIA: failed dispatcher: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-oct-2010 3:56:57 com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
ADVERTENCIA: Failed startup of context com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@24988707{/,E:\development\Tune My Party\src\main\webapp}
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.Class.isAssignableFrom(Native Method)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:256)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:185)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:147)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:219)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:164)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.<init>(DevAppServerMain.java:113)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:89)
05-oct-2010 3:56:57 com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: Started SelectChannelConnector@127.0.0.1:8888
05-oct-2010 3:56:57 com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl start
INFO: The server is running at http://localhost:8888/
```

If someone could give me an idea it will be great!!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

You don't have spring mvc jar in your classpath. Check the WEB-INF/lib directory of your web application to see if the jar file is there otherwise out it here. The jar files in this directory are loaded in classpath by default.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, probably I've set something wrong in maven. I have the idea that maven was supposed to fill all the dependencies.

Comment: My case is such that i added all the libraries in ear .Now these libraries should be accessible to all the war files.But it is not working.Does GAE does not support traditional EAR structure